# [NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfilemanager

I am trying to add a sqlite DB into an application using this: [CoreData: Preload Data in Your iOS App](http://www.behindtechlines.com/2012/05/31/coredata-preload-data-in-your-ios-app/)

Following the tutorial i hit a problem:

```
[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil
```

I use the following code:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Peter_R0_1.sqlite"];

if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[storeURL path]]) {
    NSString *sqlitePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Peter_R0_1" ofType:@"sqlite" inDirectory:nil];
    NSError *anyError = nil;
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:sqlitePath toPath:[storeURL path] error:&anyError];
}


NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
{

    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}    

return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

}

I would very much appreciate some help on this problem

Comment: Did you remember to add the `Peter_R0_1.sqlite` file to your project? Does it show up under `Copy Bundle Resources` in the project's Build Phases?

Comment: yes i have added the sqlite DB to the project.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, that error means the `NSString *sqlitePath` is `== nil` so 99% chance it's one or more of the following:

1. The file is not added to the correct Target in the project

   - Verify via "Target Membership" under the File Inspector view for the `Peter_R0_1.sqlite` file)
2. And/Or: You're copying the file to a specific sub-directory instead of the default.

   - Verify the file is listed under "Copy Bundle Resources" under your Target's "Build Phases" and NOT under "Copy Files" with a custom destination or sub-path.
3. And/Or: You've got a typo in the file name.